# Python Numpy in which Voxel is the Point?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Point-Cloud saved in a Numpy-Array like this:
    [[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],....]
Now I want to create a voxel grid with a grid size that I can change. After that Iwanna know all the Voxel in which a Point is. Is there a Numpy Method that could help me do that fast, the only idea i had so far was by solving it with slow for-loops and numpy-mask.

Comment: Not too clear. If the point is [1.23, 3.34, 5.91], then it is in the voxel [1,3,5], regardless of your point cloud (for an object?). If you want a finer grid, say in 1/10th units, then it is in voxel [12,33,59]. Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correcly one way you could populate a 3d numpy array with a set of 3d points is by using indexing.

This will work as long as your grid size is at least as big as your largest xyz value along each axis.

Note that your data will loose precision when voxelising in this way.

```
xyz = np.random.rand(50000, 3) * 100 
voxel_size = 0.5 # each voxel will be half of the pointclouds unit along each axis

xyz_q = np.round(np.array(xyz/voxel_size)).astype(int) # quantized point values, here you will loose precision

vox_grid = np.zeros((int(100/voxel_size)+1, int(100/voxel_size)+1, int(100/voxel_size)+1)) #Empty voxel grid

vox_grid[xyz_q[:,0],xyz_q[:,1],xyz_q[:,2]] = 1 # Setting all voxels containitn a points equal to 1

xyz_v = np.asarray(np.where(vox_grid == 1)) # get back indexes of populated voxels
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
points = np.random.rand(50000, 3) * 100
voxel_size = 0.5
```

Get the indices of the voxels that contain point:

```py
populated_voxel_indices = np.unique(((points - np.min(points, axis=0)) // voxel_size).astype(int), axis=0)
```